# Spring MVC /Roo - Request method 'GET' not supported

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/tusers")
@Controller
@RooWebScaffold(path = "tusers", formBackingObject = TUser.class)
public class UserController {


@RequestMapping(value = "/tusers/{id}", produces = "text/html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String show(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model uiModel) {
    uiModel.addAttribute("object", tUserService.findTUser(id));
    uiModel.addAttribute("itemId", id);
    return "tusers/show";
}
```

Why does this give me HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported on url: http://localhost:8080/twiter-roo/tusers/1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is the only code in the controller, can you try and remove the @RequestMapping annotation from the top of the class? I think it is redundant

Comment: Dani's right, the RequestMapping on the method is added to the RequestMapping on the class, so if you hit http://localhost:8080/twitter-roo/tusers/tusers/1 I suspect it would work. The problem is you don't have any handler method for the RequestMapping on the class.

Comment: I changed the mapping on the controller to: @RequestMapping(value = "/tusers") and on the method @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}") and this will handle request from http://localhost:8080/twiter-roo/tusers/1 but i also in the same controller have a method mapped with @RequestMapping(value = "/register") and i am expecting this to handle  http://localhost:8080/twiter-roo/tusers/register, but it wont (HTTP Status 400 - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect. ), any ideas here?

Comment: I guess the method mapped with "/register" is actually handling your request, the problem seems to be related to the data being sent. Could you post the code of the controller and the code that is calling the method?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I solved it some how, but I don't know what exactly I did to make it work. Must have been a path problem