# Execute main-method inside spring-application upon URL call

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've got a spring-application (Spring Roo uses Spring MVC) on a Tomcat-server.
There are some java-files inside the application. One contains a main-method.

I'd like to be able to execute this main-method when I call a URL like http://localhost/execute

How can I map this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to be able to handle http://localhost/execute request. You can use [servlet](/questions/tagged/servlet) or [spring-mvc](/questions/tagged/spring-mvc). I don't know Spring Roo, but it most likely has some mechanism to handle HTTP calls (maybe this will help: [Spring MVC /Roo - Request method 'GET' not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416908)).

Once you are able to run arbitrary code on incoming HTTP request, simply call:

```
SomeClass.main();
```

or:

```
SomeClass.main(arg1, arg2);
```

insider your servlet/controller/whatever.

Comment: I added a new definition to the TilesConfigurator which looks like this   

<definition extends="default" name="sourcescanner">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/sourcescanner.jspx"/>
    </definition>

In sourcescanner.jspx I try to execute SomeClass.main(); but it doesn't recognize my classes. Will this approach work, what do I need to do now?

Answer (score 0):

Morning,

calling a method from a class requires you to instatiate this class (or have it instatiated by Spring) and then to call your main method on that object.

As noted in the comments, since your main-Method is a static method, you can call it just on the class level, like this: MyClass.main(args)

Does that help you?

Comment: This `main` is (probably) a static method.

Answer (score 0):

Maain is just a regular static method. Just call it: `MyClass.main("aaa", "bbb");` where `MyClass` is the class you want to call, `"aaa"` and `"bbb"` are the "command line" parameters.